# Java найти пересечение двух отрезков

Tags: java, математика

Для данного класса Point и скелета класса Segment реализуйте Segment методы:

конструктор с начальной и конечной точками в качестве параметров.
Убедитесь, что созданный сегмент существует и не является дегенеративным, что означает, что начало и конец сегмента не являются одной и той же точкой.

double length()
Возвращает длину сегмента.

Point middle()
Верните среднюю точку сегмента.

Point intersection(Segment another)
Возвращает точку пересечения текущего и данного отрезка.
Вернуть, nullесли такой точки нет.
Вернуть, nullесли сегменты коллинеарны.
Обратите внимание, что точка пересечения должна лежать на обоих отрезках.

```
class Point {
private double x;
private double y;

public Point(final double x, final double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}
}

class Segment {

public Segment(Point start, Point end) {

}

double length() {

}

Point middle() {

}

Point intersection(Segment another) {

}

}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    {
        double length = new Segment(new Point(0, 0), new Point(3, 4)).length();
        System.out.println(length);
    }

    {
        Segment first = new Segment(new Point(0, 0), new Point(4, 4));
        Segment second = new Segment(new Point(2, 0), new Point(0, 2));
        Point intersection = first.intersection(second);

        System.out.println(intersection.getX());
        System.out.println(intersection.getY());
    }

    {
        Segment first = new Segment(new Point(0, 0), new Point(4, 0));
        Segment second = new Segment(new Point(2, 1), new Point(1, 2));
        Point intersection = first.intersection(second);

        System.out.println(intersection == null);
    }
    }
    }
```

Смог наваять не работающее вот это:

```
public class Segment {

class Segment {
    Point start;
    Point end;

    public Segment(Point start, Point end) {

        try {
            if (start.equals(end) || start.equals(null) || end.equals(null)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;


        double length () {
            return length = Math.sqrt((Math.pow((end.getX() - start.getX()), 2)) + Math.pow((end.getY() - start.getY()), 2));
        }

        Point middle () {
            return middle();
            x = (start.getX() + end.getX()) / 2;
            y = (start.getY() + end.getY()) / 2;
        }

        Point intersection (Segment another){

        }

    }
}
```

}

Собственно вопросы:

1.Так ли и там ли я провожу проверки сегмента?

2.Как правильно реализовать методы lenght и middle?

3.Как реализовать intersection?

Comment: Дегенеративным?? Английское слово degenerate обычно всё же переводят как «вырожденный».

Comment: Проверка аргументов должна быть в конструкторе, но выброшенное вами исключение не надо тут же ловить (какой смысл был тогда его бросать?). По поводу пересечения, вам придётся решить систему из двух линейных уравнений, найти таким образом пересечение прямых, а потом проверить, лежит ли результат на каждом из отрезков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, код сюда "руками" переписан. В том виде, как он здесь помещён, он вообще не должен компилироваться -- у вас метод `double length ()` и все другие оказались помещены внутрь конструктора:

```
class Segment {
  // ... Поля класса 

  public Segment(Point start, Point end) { // Заголовок конструктора
    // Тело конструктора:  
    try {
      // ...
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      // ...
    }
    // ... Еще какой-то код
    // Тело конструктора не закончилось 

    double length() { // Начинается другой метод 
      // который расположен прямо в теле конструктора
    } // Закончился метод length() 

    // ... И еще другие методы 

  } // И вот только здесь закончилось тело конструктора 
} // закончился класс
```

Так нельзя. Метод не может быть просто так вложен в другой метод. В методе может быть описан локальный класс, а в нем свои методы, но это совсем другая история.

---

### По существу заданных вопросов:

1. Проверки аргументов сделаны в принципе правильно, но исключение ловить в конструкторе не надо (в этом нет никакого смысла, как верно заметил @VladD). Ваша задача -- известить вызывающий код, что аргументы конструктора неприемлемы, для этого исключение должно дойти до того кода, из которого вызван конструктор класса `Segment`
2. Метод `length()` у вас реализован правильно, только не очень удобно, что строка такая длинная. Лучше бы разбить ее на части. Код должен легко читаться, в большинстве случаев это главный критерий качества кода (ну не считая его правильности, конечно).
   В методе `middle()` прямо в первой строчке очень грубая ошибка, т. наз. "дурная рекурсия". Первое, что делает метод -- вызывает себя самого. Будучи вызван, он снова первым делом вызывает себя самого. И так до бесконечности, точнее, до тех пор, пока программа не вылетит с тем самым сообщением, в честь которого назван этот сайт. Код, который идет дальше, правильно определяет середину отрезка, маленькая неприятность состоит только в том, что этот код никогда не выполнится.
3. По поводу точки пересечения -- @VladD уже написал в комменте подсказку. Чуть подробнее -- из координат начала и конца отрезков найдите уравнения, описывающие соответствующие прямые, например, вида `Y = a*X + b`, точнее, найдите значения `a` и `b` для каждого из отрезков. У вас будет два таких уравнения с двумя неизвестными `x` и `y`, их решение и будет координатами точки пересечения. Это математика AFAIR за пятый или шестой класс. Только не забудьте проверить, что прямые не параллельны (коэффициенты `a` для двух отрезков не равны друг другу) и точка пересечения лежит внутри каждого из отрезков.

В общем, если это всё принять во внимание, должен получиться какой-то такой код:

```
  class Segment {

    private Point start;
    private Point end;

    public Segment(Point start, Point end) {
      if (start == null || end == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arguments can't be null");
      if (start.equals(end))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The points must differ");
      this.start = start;
      this.end = end;
    }

    double length() {
      double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(start.getX() - end.getX(), 2);
      double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(start.getY() - end.getY(), 2);
      return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }

    Point middle() {
      return new Point( (start.getX() + end.getX()) / 2,
                        (start.getY() + end.getY()) / 2 );
    }

    Point intersection(Segment another) {
      // Координаты точки пересечения найдите сами  
      double x = 5; // Это просто пример, чтоб компилятор не ругался
      double y = 25;
      // И верните точку с этими координатами 
      return new Point(x, y);
    }

  }
```

Comment: start.equals(end) - он вызывает java object.equals

Comment: @GennadiyZolotaryov Да, верно. В классе point надо переопределить метод `equals().` Я не заметил, что его там нету.