# методы класса Segment (найти точку пересечения)

Tags: java

Уже много на эту тему написано вот здесь [Java найти пересечение двух отрезков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1269455/java-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2), но я не могу разобраться с Point intersection(Segment another) {}

Вот так выглядит весь код. Подскажите, как получить точку пересечения в методе
//Point intersection(Segment second) {}

```java
class Point {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(final double x, final double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

```java
class Segment {
    private Point start;
    private Point end;
    
    public Segment(Point start, Point end) {
    
        if (start == null || end == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have null points");
        } else if (start.equals(end)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The points must differ");
        }
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    
    public Point getStart() {
        return start;
    }
    
    public Point getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
    
    double length() {
    
        double xDistanceSquare = Math.pow(start.getX() - end.getX(), 2);
        double yDistanceSquare = Math.pow(start.getY() - end.getY(), 2);
        return Math.sqrt(xDistanceSquare + yDistanceSquare);
    }
    
    Point middle() {
        return new Point((start.getX() + end.getX()) / 2,
                (start.getY() + end.getY()) / 2);
    }
    
    Point intersection(Segment another) {
    
        if (isParallel(another)) {
            return null;
        }
        return getIntersection(another);
    
    }
    
    private boolean isParallel(Segment to) {
        return start == to.start;
    
    }
    
    public Point getIntersection(Segment second) {
        Point line1x = getStart();
        Point line1y = getEnd();
        Point line2x = second.getStart();
        Point line2y = second.getEnd();

        double x = (line2x.getX() - line1x.getX()) / (line1y.getY() - line2y.getY());
        double y = (line1x.getX() * line2y.getY() - line2x.getX() * line1y.getY()) / (line1y.getX() - line2y.getY());
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: если тупо вбить в поисковик нужные три слова, то вывалится куча статей, в некоторых даже есть готовый код. А сейчас вопрос выглядит как "я ничего не могу, сделайте за меня".

Comment: Если не сложно, скинь ссылку. Я думаю, что перерыл все решения, которые только есть на английском и на русском и не нашел решения. Не могу расчехлить формулу пересечения. Сейчас добавлю, что есть, чтоб не казалось "сделайте за меня"

Comment: https://vscode.ru/prog-lessons/nayti-tochku-peresecheniya-otrezkov.html, или вот на хабре https://habr.com/ru/post/578746/, там в самом начале еще две ссылки

Comment: Спасибо. Видел. Согласен, таких примеров несколько десятков можно найти за 5 минут. Возможно стоило уточнить, что я ограничен конкретным требованием и все эти примеры никак мне не помогают. По идее мой метод правильный, только ошибка в формуле. Кто-то может глянуть на формулы?

double x = (line2x.getX() - line1x.getX()) / (line1y.getY() - line2y.getY());
        double y = (line1x.getX() * line2y.getY() - line2x.getX() * line1y.getY()) / (line1y.getX() - line2y.getY());

Comment: `isParallel` - хрень, так что надо с этого начать.

Comment: Уважаемое сообщество! У меня к вам просьба выделить 15 минут своего времени, и кинуть в комментарии пару строк правильного кода. Я на него посмотрю и пойму, где я туплю. Для кого-то проблема создать объект класса или цикл для заполнения многомерного массива, а для меня проблема с пониманием метода intersection. Все мы находимся на разных уровнях и я искренне рад за тех людей, для кого эта задача является элементраной и очень надеюсь в ближайшем обозримом будущем присоединиться к вашему сословию, но пока прошу помочь, как говорится, "в лоб". А я вам отправлю лучики тепла и хорошего настроения))

Comment: P.S. Комментарии типа "хрень", прошу оставить для своего прыщавого отражения. Прыщавого потому, что взрослый человек не будет самоутверждаться за счет слабостей других. Если нечем помочь, просьба пройти мимо. Всех благ!